# Downloading Tensorflow in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi3

When I downloaded the tensorflow, I faced some problem which then caused me to delete what I have downloaded and re-download the tensorflow. But when I re-download it again and I test it in my Python, it shows an error like the following below:

```
>>> import tensorflow 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 104, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.importer import import_graph_def
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import function
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import resource_variable_ops
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import variables
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Variable(checkpointable.CheckpointableBase):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.checkpointable' has no attribute 'CheckpointableBase'
```

What is the possible solution to solve my problem?
Knowing I am using python3 for downloading the tensorflow

My new error:

```
--2019-03-08 02:41:42--  https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/release/download/v1.8.0/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.wl
```

Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.253.113, 192.30.253.112
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.113|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-03-08 02:41:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Answer (score 1):

Get Tensorflow for ARM and `pip install` :

```
wget https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v1.8.0/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl
pip3 install tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```

Comment: I tried doing same as you suggested, but it showed my an error. I have mentioned the error in my question. Please refer to it. @Rubens_Z